# Previous and next documents in CouchDB

Tags: sorting, timestamp, couchdb

I have a database containing items with a floating-point timestamp. When the user visits a page with url `/item/id/<the-id-here>`, the document with the corresponding identifier should be displayed (this is easy) along with links to the previous and next documents in chronological order, if they exist.

These links must be persistent, and items tend to appear and disappear at various timestamps based on external conditions, so I have no option to cache one or both of these identifiers in URLs.

Right now, I'm using a view sorted by timestamp to make two queries (one descending, one ascending) in order to fetch the previous and next documents.

- Can I do this with fewer requests?
- I'm afraid that floating-point precision will cause mayhem if objects have very close timestamps. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it possible to somehow maintains in the database the previous/next document for each document ?
It depends of the ratio of reads/writes that you have but it might be faster to do these two queries at each insert/delete than at each page view.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still working on solving this, but if so, you might try the follow:

1. Output the timestamp as a date array: `[2012, 04, 30, 03, 20, 35]`
2. Use `?startkey=[2012, 04, 30, 03, 20, 0]&endkey=[2012, 04, 30, 03, 20, 60]` to
   get the range of key/values in the index for the last minute (or hour, day, etc.
   depending on the granularity of what you're emitting).
3. In the client code use the timestamp of the document you're looking for siblings of, then get its siblings from the array/hash table/dictionary/vector/whatever.

That would get you down to a single GET request with the trade off of a larger response size. However, if you're using the HTTP `If-Not-Match`/`ETag` headers and some client-side caching, you may be able to get by with a single request for a larger range of documents--caching a list for the day or week range and using that cached array/whatever for later look-ups with much "lighter" hits to the server (as it would only check the `ETag` values and return "just" the `304 Not Modified` response code.

FWIW, this works with the Couchbase Server 2.0 API as well (as it's based on CouchDB's View's system/API).

Hope that helps.